# Check array for partial match (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, string, partial

I have an array of filenames which I need to check against a code, for example

```
array("120_120_435645.jpg","150_150_312312.jpg","250_250_1232327.jpg");
```

the string is "312312" so it would match "150_150_312312.jpg" as it contains that string.
If there are no matches at all within the search then flag the code as missing.

I tried in_array but this seems to any return true if it is an exact match, don't know if array_filter will do it wither...

Thanks for any advice...perhaps I have been staring at it too long and a coffee may help :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5592142/138383

Comment: I'd rather use stripos rather than `preg_` functions

Comment: The point is that you don't need a loop by using `preg_grep`.

Answer (score 16):

```
$filenames = array("120_120_435645.jpg","150_150_312312.jpg","250_250_1232327.jpg");
$matches = preg_grep("/312312/", $filenames);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 150_150_312312.jpg
)
```

Or, if you don't want to use regex, you can simply use [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366748/1438393) answer:

```
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    if (strpos($filename,'312312') !== false) {
    echo 'True';
    }
}
```

**[Demo!](http://codepad.org/9O68w43E)**